# I have an null error on FreeMarker template.process, but the map is evaluated

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

I have a oribkem with freeMarker template.process(tempName, Map<String, Object> valueMap)

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> entity  [in template "myTemplate.html.ftl" at line 128, column 56]

FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
- Failed at: #if entity.has("firstValue")  [in template "myTemplate.html.ftl" at line 128, column 51]
```

On debug my map is evaluated, but for the parser appear with null value.

I use FreeMarker 2.3.30

Thank yiu

Comment: The parser has no problem, but on runtime the problem is that there's no `entity` variable, or its value is `null`. How did you put `entity` into the data-model (or where else is it supposed to come from)?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `entity.has("firstValue")`: This is not the correct Freemarker syntax.

To access builtin use `?` instead of `.`, also Freemarker doesn't have the builtin `has` for hashes.
Refer to: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_hash.html

Comment: The error message in the question says there's no `entity` variable on the first place (or its value is `null`).